# Image is not showing up on tkinter canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

- Updated after being able to replicate te problem.

Initially I could make it work by binding a key to the canvas, why that worked I do not know, but then that stopped working too so I investigated further.

After setting up some tests I managed to make a short code that replicates the problem:

```
from tkinter import *


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.can = Canvas(master, bg="gray")
        self.can.pack()

        thing = PhotoImage(file=("./img/thing.PNG"))

        img = self.can.create_image(20, 20, image=thing)

        stuff = self.can.find_all()
        print(stuff)


app = Tk()

SomeClass(app)  # Does not work

something = SomeClass(app)  # Dos not work

# This part does work:
can = Canvas(app, bg="gray")
can.pack()
thing = PhotoImage(file=("./img/thing.PNG"))

img = can.create_image(20, 20, image=thing)

stuff = can.find_all()
print(stuff)

app.mainloop()
```

In all cases, the img show up as an item in the find_all(), but the first two does not show it on the canvas.

Also tried to put the creation of the image as a method with a bind to activate it thinking it went wrong during the init part. This did not change anything.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try assigning instance of `Timeline()` to a variable, like `timeline = Timeline(frame)`.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. I managed to make a short code that replicates the problem however, see the updated question above.

Comment: For your updated code, change `thing = ...` to `self.thing = ...` in SomeClass.

Comment: Same thing happens, but just figured out the answer just now, the image is getting garbage collected, and I just need to make the image either global or attached to something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answering my own question as I finally found out what was going wrong.

I didn't read this line in the documentation about the PhotoImage:

"You must keep a reference to the image object in your Python program, either by storing it in a global variable, or by attaching it to another object."

So in this case, the way to make it work is either do:

```
app = Tk()
thing = PhotoImage(file=("./img/thing.PNG")) # making it a global variable
```

or

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.can = Canvas(master, bg="gray")
        thing = PhotoImage(file=("./img/thing.PNG")
        self.can.img = thing   # This attaches the image to the canvas object
```

Hope this helps anyone else that comes across this problem.